# Highlight <TR> entire week datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a datepicker that is fully functional and is working whereby you can select an entire commencing working week (Mon-Fri). What I am now trying to do is extend it a little further so that when I click on a specific week. It will highlight that entire . I have it paritally working which looks like the following: [Calandar preivew](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEFkJ.png). It can be seen that the problem I am having is that the table row to me seems to be doing a odd, even, odd even. As for the first week I highlight the row is highlighted in red and the cells are hihglighted in yellow. Then the week afer that it work fines and then if I was to select the week after that the same would be repeated. I tried checking the jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.css and the jquery-ui.css, and had no luck. What seems to confuse me is why are the cells being highlighted in yellow? The code follows for my datepicker.

**Javascript:**

```
$(function() 
{
    var startDate;
    var endDate;
    var selectCurrentWeek = function() 
    {
        window.setTimeout(function () { $('.week-picker').find('.ui-datepicker-current-day a').addClass('ui-state-active')}, 1);
    }
    function check(d) {
        if(d.length() == 2) {
            dd = d;
            return dd;
        } else {
            dd = "0" + myDateParts[0];
            return dd;
        }
    }

    var selectedWeek;//remember which week the user selected here

    $('.week-picker').datepicker( {
        beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 1);
            endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 6);
            var dateFormat = 'yy-mm-dd'
            var newDate = $('#startDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, startDate, inst.settings ));

            var oldDate = document.getElementById('startDate');
            var date_textnode = oldDate.firstChild;
            var date_text = date_textnode.data;
            myDateParts = date_text.split("-");

            var dd = myDateParts[2];

            var mm = myDateParts[1];

            var yy = myDateParts[0];

            selectCurrentWeek();

            window.location.href = "/timesheet?week_commencing=" + yy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd;

        },
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {

            var cssClass = '';
            if(date >= startDate && date <= endDate)
                cssClass = 'ui-datepicker-current-day';
            return [true, cssClass];
        },
        onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
            selectCurrentWeek();
        }
    });

   $( ".week-picker" ).datepicker().click(function(event) {
    // highlight the TR
    $(".ui-datepicker-current-day").parent().addClass('highlight');

    // highlight the TD > A
    $(".ui-datepicker-calendarr-day").siblings().find('a').addClass('white');
}); 
    $('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mousemove', function() { $(this).find('td a').addClass('ui-state-hover'); });
    $('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mouseleave', function() { $(this).find('td a').removeClass('ui-state-hover'); });


});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="datepicker borderbox">
        <b><center>Hours for Week commencing: <span id="startDate"></span></center></b>
        <div class="week-picker"></div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.highlight {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.white {
    background: white !important;
}
```

I have tried looking at the following stackoverflow question [Related stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567338/jquery-ui-datepicker-highlight-7-days). Had no luck with this, as the link was broken and also tried viewing the it in JSfiddle. Further to this the way I have set my datepicker is different.

I am intially trying to get my calendar to work like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/william/YQ2Zw/2/) But for some reason when I try do this I get the following. Is this something to do with the css

**Update2**

[Calendar & Firebug output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEsd5.png)

Comment: It seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/nayish/YQ2Zw/

Comment: I checked out the jsfiddle you supplied and tested it. This seemed to not work I have updated my post

Comment: I just made the change you replied really fast ;)

Comment: I can't actually see on my computer how it renders so I can't really help... sorry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/william/YQ2Zw/2/

There were a couple of things that went wrong:

The `ui-datepicker-current-day` class was applied to a `<td>` element, so it only needs to travel one level up to find the `<tr>`, so I took away one call to `parent()`:

```
$(".ui-datepicker-current-day").parent().addClass('highlight');
```

You set multiple days with the `ui-datepicker-current-day` class. That was why I needed to use the `:eq(0)` selector to only select the first element:

```
$(".ui-datepicker-current-day:eq(0)").siblings().find('a').addClass('white');
```

Also, you were calling the wrong class for the statement above.

Comment: Yeah it was precisely what I was trying to do where is it that I was going wrong?

Comment: I checked the jsfiddle and it gave me the similar error I was getting before. I can't seem to understand why the cells are being highlighted yellow. I think it may have something to do with my jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom

Comment: fiddle is missing