# Highlight entire <tr> week in bootstrap datepicker

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, hover

Similarly to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187796/highlight-tr-entire-week-datepicker), in which an answer provided [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/william/YQ2Zw/2/), I'd like to highlight the entire week of my bootstrap datepicker, not jQuery UI.

My code is currently this:

```
$('.datepicker-days tbody tr').live('mousemove', function () {
    $(this).find('td day').addClass('highlight');
});
$('.datepicker-days tbody tr').live('mouseleave', function () {
    $(this).find('td day').removeClass('highlight');
});
```

"Highlight" is not the right class to be adding and removing, as far as I can tell.

The selector in the datepicker CSS file for hovered cells is:

```
.datepicker td.day:hover { background: #eeeeee; cursor: pointer; }
```

Is there a way to add "hover" as a "class"?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to add via jQuery the `:hover` pseudo class.

Comment: Please don't use `.live()` for the sake of performance, if nothing else. jQuery has deprecated the `.live()` function in favor of `$(document).on('event', 'selector', function(){ //code to run when event fires});`. `.live()` chooses the **longest and slowest path**, which is terrible when documents are large, or, when elements are *deeply* nested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add any class you want. If you want the same css as the hover rule shown just add  a new rule for your class and make it specific enough that other css rules won't out rank it. You can inspect all rules that apply to any element in a browser console

Example css:

```
 .datepicker td.highlight { background: #eeeeee; cursor: pointer; }
```

Using `mousemove` is not really appropriate, change to `mouseenter`

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking about this route but was hoping there would be a method to "fake" adding the "hover" pseudo class. I've changed the mousemove to mouseenter, not entirely sure why I had that in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `mouseenter` instead of `mousemove`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to apply a weekpicker highlight only on one datepicker  and Unfortunately its applied on all of the datepicker inside the project by using
this:

```
 .datepicker td.highlight { background: #eeeeee; cursor: pointer; }
```

it happens to me in my case for that i did it like this.

**Script**

```
$('#weeklyDatePicker').on('click', function () {

        if ($('.datepicker').hasClass('one') == false) {
            $('.datepicker').addClass('one');
        }           
    });
```

**Style**

```
   .one{
}



.one tr:hover{
  background-color: #a8a8a8;
}
```