# Select one day and give the next N days a css class

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Is it possible to select one day in the jqueryUI datepicker and than the datepicker gives the next N days a css class like 'marked-time-period'?

For example: A date goes over 3 days, and you can set a start date on the datepicker. When you clicked on the 4th november, the 5th,6th,7th get the css class 'marked-time-period'.

greetings

Comment: ok, i have the start date and the end date in an array. When the user clicks on the 4th november, i can see the next days because the array key is 2012-11-04 and the values are 2012-11-05,2012-11-06,2012-11-07. How i select the 2012-11-05,2012-11-06,2012-11-07 with jquery on the datepicker? i think this solution is simpler than calculate the next 3 days from today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, here is my solution:

`http://jsfiddle.net/tungon/buyrZ/`

the var *datesFromDatabase* are generated in PHP.

`var datesFromDatabase = {
        '16.11.2012': ['17.11.2012', '18.11.2012', '19.11.2012'],
        '17.11.2012': ['18.11.2012', '19.11.2012', '20.11.2012']
    };`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest "out of the box" way to work with this might be using the minDate and maxDate datepicker options, where maxDate gets advanced 3 days ahead of the selected date in your code.

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range

Then you could try to style the available range the way you want, where the class "ui-datepicker-unselectable" are the days you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need something like this `http://jsfiddle.net/william/YQ2Zw/2/`. Source: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187796/highlight-tr-entire-week-datepicker`